# Why is my custom UITableCell not displaying the text?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicolor, textcolor

So I tried subclassing UITableViewCell to make a message cell, I've been testing it and I can't seem to get it to show anything. It's not the data source because it was working fine with I wasn't trying to use a custom cell. I'm not sure why nothing is appearing in the cells.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    MessageCell * cell = (MessageCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[MessageCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    cell.messageContent.text = self.messages[indexPath.row][@"content"];

    return (UITableViewCell*) cell;
}
```

this is the init method i have in the subclass of UITableViewCell

```
-(instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if(self){

        //I played with the CGRect numbers but that's not it.
        messageContent = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3,35, 200,30)];

        messageContent.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        messageContent.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        messageContent.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        messageContent.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        [self.contentView addSubview:messageContent];
    }
  return self
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm that you're calling registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier: someplace to make sure that your custom cells are being provided by the deck?.  (that would be my guess about the cause of the problem)

Comment: You have to tell your tableView which class it should provide for the reuse identifier, and that's not shown anywhere. I would expect it to throw an exception though if it's a UITableViewCell and trying to access the non-existent messageContent property though. Are you doing that somewhere, viewDidLoad maybe? Alternately, although you commented about it, the frame could be an issue. It has a y origin of 35 and a height of 30, the default row height is 44 I believe. It's possible it's getting cut off and the text would be drawn outside the cell's content frame.

Comment: what does `self.messages[indexPath.row][@"content"]` return?

Comment: is messageContent a public variable? It seems like it is a privateVariable since it doesnt have _ or self. But you can access it on UITableView createCell delegate method. Do you have 2 variables . 1 private 1 public

Comment: It's a public variable synthesized in the MessageCell .m file,      self.messages[indexPath.row][@"content"] returns a string, that's not the error in the code.

Comment: I tried adding [self.tableView registerClass:[MessageCell
                                    class]forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
into viewdidload but still not seeing anything in the table view.

Answer (score 1):

1st check using below line :

```
cell.messageContent.text = @"asdfasdf";
```

If it's work properly than something wrong in

```
self.messages[indexPath.row][@"content"]
```

line  . . .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboard, the method `-(instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier;` most definitely wont get called.

Add this method to MessageCell.h:

`- (void)setupCellWithText:(NSString *)text`

Add the implementation to MessageCell.m:

```
- (void)setupCellWithText:(NSString *)text{
    messageContent = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3,35, 200,30)];

    messageContent.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    messageContent.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    messageContent.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    messageContent.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    [self.contentView addSubview:messageContent];
    messageContent.text = text;
}
```

Now modify your delegate method:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    MessageCell * cell = (MessageCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[MessageCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    [cell setupWithText:[self.messages[indexPath.row][@"content"]]];

    return (UITableViewCell*) cell;
}
```

Hope this helps. Sorry for typos.

Comment: This is giving me an "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error during run time.

Comment: Where exactly do you get that?

Comment: When I try calling the setupCellWithText method

Answer (score 0):

When you create a custom UITableViewCell your tableView needs to know about it. Here's how. This goes in the UITableViewController's viewDidLoad:

`[self.tableView registerClass:[MessageCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];`

Now your tableViews knows about your class and no more casting is necessary.

Bonus tip! You don't need this:

`if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[MessageCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }`

`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` already does that for you.

---

Here's what the whole thing would look like.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Register custom cell for table view
    [self.tableView registerClass:[MessageCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

}



-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    MessageCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    cell.messageContent.text = self.messages[indexPath.row][@"content"];

    return cell;
}
```

** I just wrote this in the browser so forgive my errors

Comment: But if initWithStyle is never called, won't the cell never get set up correctly? Since all the code formatting and styling the cell is done in that method.

Comment: Apple docs show only one initialiser. To be sure it's being called, just set a breakpoint on the initialiser.  https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW34

Answer (score 0):

Check set your `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`.

On Xib: See image below.

[image]

Or in `ViewDidLoad`:

```
self.mTableView.delegate = self;
self.mTableView.dataSource = self;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's not this. Also I don't think you need to set the delegate and dataSource in code if you do it from the xib file, am I correct?